# The songs I downloaded online do not show up with the same name in the player

Tags: downloading, troubleshooting

I download music from various sites offering music for free (because I lack any sort of disposable income to legitimately download them). After changing their names into ones that make sense on my computer, I load them onto a memory card and then try to play them. They play just fine but their titles seem to be totally different from what I changed them to on my computer. For example, I renamed a file to "The Chainsmokers-Closer"  on my computer, but in Google play music it reads "TERGOS. RU". What is causing this and how can I solve it? Should I format the memory card as input? Should I put the renamed files directly onto my internal memory? Re downloading the song doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Music is most likely reading the MP3 tag instead of the actual filename. There are two ways to edit the MP3 tag.

To do it on your computer, I have used in the past [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/). To do this from your phone, you can use the application [iTag - Music Tag Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.itag&hl=en). If you prefer neither of these methods, you would have to find a music player that does not read the MP3 tag but instead reads the filename. I use [Poweramp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&hl=en) and in the settings of that application, under `Look & Feel > Player UI`, you can set the player to read the titles from the file names.